# How design user point system database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

In my application ,there is two pointing system. coffeepoints and sandwich points. I am looking best approach to design database.

Coffee points :-  When user purchase coffee, he will earn coffee points
sandwich points :- When user purchase sandwich he will earn in sandwich points

1 method :-  Create a table, point_types to store points name such as coffe points and sandwitch points
[image]

2 method :- use coffe_points and sandwitch points as field_name wherever points data stored.

[image]

Which one is best approach?

Comment: Will you need other point types in future?

Comment: to answer that kind of question you should start by explaining what is a coffe/sandwitch point in your application.

Comment: @Nemeros updated with description of coffee/sandwich points

Comment: @Maxx only 10% chance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a pure conceptual modelisation point of view the first solution is the way to go.

It gives your model flexibility and answer to the case without breaking normal forms.

I wouldn't implement the second solution, till you would have to work on several sql query if your fonctionnality ever evolve (10% chance)

Comment: Thank you for reply... I confirmed with first solution. :)